# Combining lists of tuples based on a common tuple element

Tags: python, list

Consider two lists of tuples:

```
data1 = [([X1], 'a'), ([X2], 'b'), ([X3], 'c')]
data2 = [([Y1], 'a'), ([Y2], 'b'), ([Y3], 'c')]
```

Where `len(data1) == len(data2)`

Each tuple contains two elements:

1. list of some strings (i.e `[X1]`)
2. A **common** element for `data1` and `data2`: strings `'a'`, `'b'`, and so on.

I would like to combine them into following:

```
[('a', [X1], [Y1]), ('b', [X2], [Y2]),...]
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: @Idio, yes I did but was willing to see other's folk's idea's, what turns out to be very helpfull.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `zip` function and a list comprehension:

```
[(s1,l1,l2) for (l1,s1),(l2,s2) in zip(data1,data2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

[@Kasramvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867928/kasramvd)'s solution is good *if the order is the same among all elements in the `data` lists*. If they are not, it doesn't take that into account.

A solution that *does*, utilizes a **[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)**:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)  # values are initialized to empty list

data1 = [("s1", 'a'), ("s2", 'c'), ("s3", 'b')]
data2 = [("s1", 'c'), ("s2", 'b'), ("s3", 'a')]

for value, common in data1 + data2:
    d[common].append(value)
```

In order to get a list of it, simply wrap it in a [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) call:

```
res = list(d.items())
print(res)
# Prints: [('b', ['s3', 's2']), ('a', ['s1', 's3']), ('c', ['s2', 's1'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in a single comprehension expression, using the reduce function

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
[tuple([x]+reduce(add,([y[0]] for y in data1+data2 if y[1]==x))) for x in set(y[1] for y in data1+data2)]
```

If the lists are large, so that `data1+data2` imposes a severe time or memory penalty, it might be better to pre-compute it

```
combdata = data1+data2
[tuple([x]+reduce(add,[y[0]] for y in combdata if y[1]==x))) for x in set(y[1] for y in combdata)]
```

This solution does not rely on all "keys" occurring in both lists, or the order being the same.

If returned order is important, we can even do

```
sorted([tuple([x]+reduce(add,([y[0]] for y in data1+data2 if y[1]==x))) for x in set(y[1] for y in data1+data2)],key = lambda x,y=[x[0] for x in data1+data2]: y.index(x[1]))
```

to ensure that the order is the same as in the original lists.  Again, pre-computing `data1+data2` gives

```
sorted([tuple([x]+reduce(add,([y[0]] for y in combdata if y[1]==x))) for x in set(y[1] for y in combdata)],key = lambda x,y=[x[0] for x in combdata]: y.index(x[1]))
```